# PostgreSQL multicolumn index not fully used

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, postgresql-12

I have a large (~110 million rows) table on PostgreSQL 12.3 whose relevant fields can be described by the following DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    item1_id integer,
    item2_id integer,
    item3_id integer,
    item4_id integer,
    type_id integer
)
```

One of the queries we execute often is:

```sql
SELECT type_id, item1_id, item2_id, item3_id, item4_id
FROM tbl
WHERE
    type_id IS NOT NULL
    AND item1_id IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND (
        item2_id IN (4, 5, 6)
        OR item2_id IS NULL
    )
    AND (
        item3_id IN (7, 8, 9)
        OR item3_id IS NULL
    )
    AND (
        item4_id IN (10, 11, 12)
        OR item4_id IS NULL
    )
```

Although we have indexes for each of the individual columns, the query is still relatively slow (a couple of seconds). Hoping to optimize this, I created the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX tbl_item_ids
    ON public.tbl USING btree
    (item1_id ASC, item2_id ASC, item3_id ASC, item4_id ASC)
    WHERE type_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Unfortunately the query performance barely improved - `EXPLAIN` tells me this is because although an index scan is done with this newly created index, only `item1_id` is used as an `Index Cond`, whereas all the other filters are applied at table level (i.e. plain `Filter`).

I'm not sure why the index is not used in its entirety (or at least for more than the `item1_id` column). Is there an obvious reason for this? Is there a way I can restructure the index or the query itself to help with performance?

Comment: How many rows (or percentage of rows) does this query return in average? Are the numbers 1 to 12 parameters that could have any value and change often?

Comment: @TheImpaler the query will return anywhere between 100 and 30k rows. On average, around 5k. The amount of values in the IN clauses will vary between a couple and 100 at most, with an average of around 20 (this doesn't seem to have an effect on the plan, from my experiments).

Comment: I would do a couple of things: 1) Add `item1_id IS NOT NULL` to the `WHERE` clause of the partial index, in order to make the index smaller. 2) I would sort the item_ids from the most selective to the least selective (according to your stats and experience) and place them in that order in the index. As a side note `ASC` doesn't really have any effect since you are not performing range scans.

Comment: Thanks @TheImpaler. In my experience item1 should be the most selective, but I tried a few other permutations to no avail. So far the best I could do was an index on `item1_id, type_id` with `INCLUDE (item2_id, item3_id, item4_id)`. I used `type_id` and didn't use a `WHERE` clause so I can drop the single-column index on `item1_id` if I do choose this option. This results in an index-only scan with a ~33% speedup over my original index. I'll try upgrading to 12.4 to see if that makes any difference, though.

Answer (score 2):

A multi-column index can only be used for more than the first column if the condition on the first column uses an equality comparison (`=`). `IN` or `= ANY` does not qualify.

So you will be better off with individual indexes for each column, which can be combined with a bitmap or.

You should try to avoid `OR` in the `WHERE` condition, perhaps with

```
WHERE coalesce(item2_id, -1) IN (-1, 4, 5, 6)
```

where -1 is a value that doesn't occur. Then you could use an index on the `coalesce` expression.

Comment: "*A multi-column index can only be used for more than the first column if the condition on the first column uses an equality comparison*" - thanks, I wasn't aware of that. That's actually a bit disappointing. Is there a technical limitation for that, or just a case of "*no one bothered to implement it*"

Comment: When I say "can only be used" I mean "can only be used efficiently", and I omitted the use case of index only scans. It would need something like an "index skip scan" to do better; there is a patch in the pipeline, but we don't have it yet.